# Is there a better way to read several txt files in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have several files with aprox 1M rows.

This is a sample of the file content:

```
begin(model(tb4)).
...
sequence_length(187).
amino_acid_pair_ratio(a,a,24.8).
amino_acid_pair_ratio(a,c,0.0).
...
tb_to_tb_evalue(tb3671,1.100000e-01).
tb_to_tb_evalue(tb405,4.300000e-01).
tb_to_tb_evalue(tb3225,5.600000e-01).
...
end(model(tb4))
begin(model(tb56)).
......
end(model(tb56))
```

By having an input like

```
myarray = (tb4, tb56..)
```

I need to calculate how many lines of the type "tb_to_tb_evalue" are contained in each model.

In this case, with the sample text, the output should be:
tb4 = 3
tb56 = 0

I have done this so far but I realized I will have to read all file as many times as len(myarray)

```
def readorfs():
    # Declaramos la ruta de la carpeta que almacena los ficheros
    path = "data/orfs"
    # Recogemos los nombres de los ficheros
    all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
    # Leemos los ficheros line a linea
    for filename in all_files:
        with open(filename) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()  # Lee el fichero line a linea
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith("begin(model(") and (myarray[i]) in line:
                    print(line)
```

Comment: you could read them all in one go with padnas but depends on the memory usage of each file and what you need to do. you could read each part in a chunk, i would recommend jut throwing the files into a database and pulling out what you need for your analysis.

Comment: You can invert your loop, so that you open a single file and then loop through all of `myarray` before moving onto the next file

Comment: need to calculate how many lines of the type "tb_to_tb_evalue" are contained in each model. How can I do it with pandas? I suppose I can apply reggex or something after? @Manakin

Comment: If by "better way" you are concerned about keeping memory usage smaller, you skip creating lines form f.readlines() (which loads all lines in memory), and just  iterate over the file handle f which will give you each line as in `for line in f:`

Comment: myarray is a list or a dict? Also you want to get the count for each file separately or in total?

Comment: myarray is a numpy.ndarray @IoaTzimas

Comment: You want to get the count for each file separately or in total?

Comment: In total, actually I need an average so it will be something like tb5 = 4, tb6 = 8. Then (4+8)/2 @IoaTzimas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using a `defaultdict` from `collections` which will get your specific model name as the key and the count of `tb_to_tb_evalue` lines for that model as the value. Because you're reading all the files completely, there is no real extra overhead to find the counts of *all* the models. But it would be straightforward in the end to get the counts for your specific models from a list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re
tb_count = defaultdict(int)
# create regular expression to find the model name from the "begin(model(...))" lines
model_regex = re.compile(r"begin\(model\((.*)\)\)")
for file in all_filenames:
    model = None  # initiate model as None for each file, but value will be changed if begin(model( line is encountered
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("begin(model("):
                # identify the model name
                match = model_regex.search(line)
                if match:
                    model = match.group(1)
            if line.startswith("tb_to_tb_evalue("):
                tb_count[model] += 1  # increase the count for the current active model
```

So it will iterate through all your files *but only once*. At the end to get the count of all the models from a specific list (e.g. `myarray`), you can write something like:

```
models_of_interest = {k: v for k, v in tb_count.items() if k in myarray }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:
Firstly create a dictionary with all items of myarray as keys and values=0
Then, create a function that will handle a specific file. Load the entire file as text, split it by '(begin(model(' and count all occurencies of 'tb_to_tb_evalue'. Add all results to the dictionary.
Finally run this function for all files.
See below:

```
d={i:0 for i in myarray}
def readorfs(file):
    t=open(file).read()
    l=t.split(sep='begin(model(')[1:]
    for i in l:
        s=i[:i.find(')')]
        if s in d:
            d[s]+=i.count('tb_to_tb_evalue')
        else:
            d[s]=i.count('tb_to_tb_evalue')

for filename in all_files:
    readorfs(filename)
```

You can also run all files in one function as below. In this case, you must insert myarray in function parameter:

```
def readorfs(myarray):
    d={i:0 for i in myarray}
    path = "data/orfs"
    all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
    for filename in all_files:
        t=open(file).read()
        l=t.split(sep='begin(model(')[1:]
        for i in l:
            s=i[:i.find(')')]
            if s in d:
                d[s]+=i.count('tb_to_tb_evalue')
            else:
                d[s]=i.count('tb_to_tb_evalue')
    return d
```

Comment: I this case, I should do it inside the all_files loop, since its not only 1 file? Note that you only have to count 'tb_to_tb_evalue' between begin (model (myarray [i])). and end (model (myarray [i]))

Comment: Yes you can do it. I added a second version for it

Comment: It returns me this error:  File "C:/Users/blabla", line 125, in readorfs2
    d[s]+=i.count('tb_to_tb_evalue')
KeyError: 'tb5'

Comment: I just did, my array is myarray = ["tb4", "tb14"]

Comment: Then probably 'tb5' is not inlcuded in myarray. I will do some changes in my solution. You can also use an OrderedDict for this, as it handles not existing keys better

Comment: No its not, files can have tbx not included in myarray

Comment: That's the reason because i was checking if begin(model( row had myarray[i]

Comment: I did some changes, please try again

Comment: It looks better now, I'll check it and text you later. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great, a slight correction to my previous message: we can avoid the if statement at the end (`if s in d:`) etc by using a defaultdict.
(Result will be the same exactly though, no differences)

Comment: Did it work @Thony? If yes, don't forget to accept  answer so that question will leave from 'unanswered' queue. Cheers

Comment: No it didnt, if I set myarray to myarray = ["tb4"] it should return 28 ocurrences. It returns 25015 :(

Comment: Sorry, i had an error in `s=...` line. I have fixed that, it should work now

Comment: Both solutions are great and I really apreciate your help.